# Black & White color filter wth negative effect ImageView Android

Tags: android, filter, colors, imageview

I tried lot of color matrix for imageView to look as white text with black background but i am unable to find a suitable solution.
[Check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZt9y.png)

I tried this color matrix but it is a colored negative effect.

```
 float[] mx = new float[]{
            -1.0f, 0, 0, 0, 255, //red
            0, -1.0f, 0, 0, 255, //green
            0, 0, -1.0f, 0, 255, //blue
            0, 0, 0, 1.0f, 0 //alpha
    };
```

And i tried this and this is a grayscale effect

```
mx = new float[]{
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 0,
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 0,
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
            -1, -1, -1, 0, 1
    };
```

Comment: It's a 2 step process. First, turn the image to greyscale. Then Invert it.

Comment: Can you explain these two steps please,

Comment: You already have them: Use the Colormatrices in the order I told you. But the second time work on the new image (which results from the previous transformation).

Comment: Thanks Man , you saved my day...I don it by Combining the two Color matrix and then applied to ImageView.

Comment: Very well done. Next step: answer your own question and accept your answer (I guess you will have to wait a couple of days prior to be able to accept it).